# xml Parsing using python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

Below is the XML that I am trying to parse, but it is giving me the error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 2, column 0
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:NWEnv>
    <name>lk</name>
    <gateways>        
        <IPAddress>1.2.3.2</IPAddress>
    </gateways>
    <DNSServers>        
        <IPAddress>1.2.4.3</IPAddress>
    </DNSServers>
    <doesOverride>false</doesOverride>
    <auditUpload>0</auditUpload>
</ns1:NWEnv>
```

Comment: Well what *is* `ns1`?

Answer (score 1):

Your xml has an error.  The `ns1:` prefix is not bound to a namespace.  There should be a namespace declaration in your xml using the xmlns attribute.

> When using prefixes in XML, a so-called namespace for the prefix must
>   be defined.
>   The namespace is defined by the xmlns attribute in the start tag of an
>   element.
>   The namespace declaration has the following syntax.
>   xmlns:prefix="URI".

*Source*: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

The xml will parse when you define the namespace for the `ns1:` prefix.  The following parses:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:NWEnv xmlns:ns1="http://put.what.you.like.here.org/nwenv">
    <name>lk</name>
    <gateways>        
        <IPAddress>1.2.3.2</IPAddress>
    </gateways>
    <DNSServers>        
        <IPAddress>1.2.4.3</IPAddress>
    </DNSServers>
    <doesOverride>false</doesOverride>
    <auditUpload>0</auditUpload>
</ns1:NWEnv>
```